# Fetching second row from csv file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, export-to-csv

```
actual_row = File.open(file_name[0], 'r')
 first_row_data = []
 CSV.foreach(actual_row) do |row| 
first_row_data << row[1]
 end 
puts first_row_data
```

With this I am trying to fetch the second row of CSV but it is printing the second column instead.

Answer (score 4):

The `foreach` method returns an enumerator if no block is given, which allows you to use methods such as [`drop`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-drop) from `Enumerable`:

```
# outputs all rows after the first
CSV.foreach('test.csv').drop(1).each { |row| puts row.inspect }
```

To limit to just one row, we can then [`take`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-take):

```
# outputs only the second row
CSV.foreach('test.csv').drop(1).take(1).each { |row| puts row.inspect }
```

But, we're still parsing the entire file and just discarding most of it. Luckily, we can add [`lazy`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-lazy) into the mix:

```
# outputs only the second row, parsing only the first 2 rows of the file
CSV.foreach('test.csv').lazy.drop(1).take(1).each { |row| puts row.inspect }
```

But, if the first row is a header row, don't forgot you can tell CSV about it:

```
# outputs only the second row, as a CSV::Row, only parses 2 rows
CSV.foreach('test.csv', headers: true).take(1).each { |row| puts row.inspect }
```

---

As an aside (in case I did this wrong), it looks like the `shift` method is what CSV is using for parsing the rows, so I just added:

```
class CSV
  alias :orig_shift :shift

  def shift
    $stdout.puts "shifting row"

    orig_shift
  end
end
```

and ran with a sample csv to see how many times "shifting row" was output for each of the examples.

Comment: Great idea!!!! In this case, `second_row=CSV.foreach('test.csv').lazy.take(2).last` should work as well, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like the entire row, you should change

`row[1]`

to just

`row`

row[1] is grabbing the second column's value of the entire row.  Each column value is stored sequentially in the row variable.  You can see this directly in your console if you print

`puts row.inspect`

If you want just the second row, you can try something like this:

```
actual_row = File.open(file_name[0], 'r')
first_row_data = []
CSV.foreach(actual_row) do |row| 
  if $. == 1
    first_row_data << row
  end
end 
puts first_row_data
```

You can learn more about `$.` and similar variables here: https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/globals_rdoc.html

Comment: What if I want to fetch only second row .with "row" it is fetching all the rows at a time.

Comment: Hi @surabhi8960 - I've updated the answer to give you an idea of how to grab just the second row.

Comment: Thank you so much Anthony L

Comment: @AnthonyL : I think you should add a `break` after storing the row, as the OP said that he doesn't want to process the whole file.